# iwlwifi: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5

Tags: wifi, thinkpad, firmware, iwlwifi

After using my laptop for a while, wifi drops and kernel returns

```
iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Could not load the [0] uCode section
iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Unable to initialize device.
```

I'm running on an x230 running

> 03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to recover from this is to remove the device, and rescan. This forces the kernel to re-add the device, and resolves all wifi issues.

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/remove
sleep 3
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/pci/rescan
```

This assumes your device is `0000:03:00.0` you can find this number with `lspci | grep Centrino`

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

---

- [Answer provided by bakedcow on /r/archlinux](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/57jyvt/iwlwifi_error_causes_wifi_connectivity_loss_only/)

Answer (score 3):

This problem was solved for me when I blacklisted `intel_ips` in `/etc/modules` file. No more `iwlwifi` solo drops.

I know the question is old, but I hope I can help someone to save some time solving this issue.

**PS:** I am using Arch Linux under Lenovo x201. The `modules` file can be different depending on your distro.